# Use of 'treeNodeFullTemplate' of angular-tree-component not clear

Tags: angular, angular-tree-component

I'm trying to use the `#treeNodeFullTemplate` in my app in order to fully customize the component, but I don't seem to be able to view my datas after copying the new template described in [here](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/templates#treenodefulltemplate).

My datas don't have the `name` property, so I want to display the label of each node using another property, but I'm failing at that.

I tried to combine this new template with the previous ones (`#treeNodeTemplate` and `#loadingTemplate`), but nothing seems to work, and reading the docs isn't really helping me right now.

How can I tell the component to look for the property `otherName` instead of `name`?

I made an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-component-full-template).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set options for your `name` property as `ohterName`. [Read more about features of `ITreeOptions` here](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/options-2):

```
import { TREE_ACTIONS, KEYS, IActionMapping, ITreeOptions } from 'angular-tree-component';

options: ITreeOptions = {
    allowDrag: (node) => {
      return true;
    },
    displayField: 'ohterName',
    allowDrop: (node) => {
      return true;
    },
  };
```

[A work stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-component-full-template-agzmrq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: My gosh, it was so simple... my dumbness blinded me, I even used the `hasChildrenField` before. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndreaPruccoli it is okay. Glad to help you! :)